# Information not Visible in Source File View

Tags: html, ajax, extjs, inspect-element

i have recently started using Senchs extJS.. when we see the source file it only displays what ever is the written code, but what the style has applied or any script that added later is not there in the "View Source"

Same for AJAX, when we load anything in any container, it is not there...

but if we're using Chrome and we inspect the element, it show everything....

**WHY this behavior?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View Source in browsers typically only displays the downloaded source *without* running anything at all (including any JS that would modify the DOM).  In fact, *at least* Chrome will create a *separate request* when you view source to get that code.

As for the reason **why**, I'm not sure exactly.  This is just the standard and is the way that "view source" has worked for long before I was ever a web developer.  It is similar to doing a raw HTTP request (i.e. you just get the source; nothing runs to change it).  The term "Source" indicates the origin of what you have received, unmodified (think "source code.")

Comment: that's what exactly i wanted to know... so "Inspect Element shows the current state of DOM"

Comment: @JunaidSaeed correct; with Chrome you can easily get the modified DOM ("Copy as HTML" on the `<html>` element)

Comment: now another problem is raised.. if not then in my head at-least... what about S.E.O, the s-engines and spiders are gonna traverse my generated source or the current DOM instance, cuz there could be scenarios where both can become a lot different...

Comment: @JunaidSaeed you should do research elsewhere, but I can tell you that that is correct.  You need to have a method of serving important content than can handle browsers without JS

Comment: @ExplosionPills to elaborate, right click and inspect element to bring up the inspector window, then on the element, right click again and edit as html to view it (in Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Because that's just how it works. View source only shows the page when it was first served up to the browser.